# How to count line of code with some condition

Tags: text-processing

- Ignore empty lines
- Ignore lines having spaces only
- Ignore lines having tabs only
- Ignore lines starting with `//`

Just want to add this
To count block comment 
I am trying to use script

```
sed '/  "/*"   /,/   "*\"   / p'  a.txt | wc -l
```

/Star  Star/
For example

Code 
Count every line that falls within  /* */ including lines having /* and */

```
/*
ABC
Def
Thi
*/
```

Comment: What about lines having combination of space and tab and lines consisting of only a CR character (empty MSDOS line) which C compilers even Unix ones will typically ignore? Shall lines with spaces and/or tabs before the `//` also be ignored?

Comment: Never thought in such depth ,basically I have c language file I want to create a script to count loc , also I forget to mention block comment removal   , by naked eye , a line having no code should not be counted ...

Comment: for multline comments removal, see [Remove multi-line comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061785/remove-multi-line-comments)

Comment: -1 Now you're asking two different questions!

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep -c` to count matching lines with `-v` to invert the match:

```
grep -cv -e '^\s*$' -e '^\s*//' yourcode.c
```

Replace `\s` with the standard `[[:space:]]` equivalent if your `grep` implementation doesn't support it.

*(And don't forget to redirect the result to `/dev/null` as the value has no useful meaning at all.)*

Comment: Note that `\s` aka `[[:space:]]` match on a lot more than space and tab (but that's probably alright and even a good idea as it also matches on the CR character that one may find in C/C++ files coming from Microsoft systems, and the other ones that  `\s` match like form feed, vertical tab and all Unicode spacing characters would typically not be found anyway in C/C++ files)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` and `wc`.

```
sed -E -n '\:^[ \t]*$|^[ \t]*//:!p' infile |wc -l
```

- Ignore lines only Spaces, Tabs, Empty lines `^[ \t]*$`
- Ignore lines starting with `//`, `^//` or `^[ \t]*//` to skip if those have whitespaces.
- `wc -l` count rest lines which `sed` will output, you could replace it with `sed -n '$='`

Or replacing `[ \t]*` with `\s*`.

```
sed -E -n '\:^\s*$|^\s*//:!p' infile
```

**`awk` solution.**

```
awk '!/^[ \t]*$/ && !/^[ \t]*\/\//{N++} END{print N}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NF > 0 && !/^\/\// { c++ } END { print c }'
```

`awk` uses a regular expression to split each line into fields. This regular expression splits on spaces and tabs by default.

If the number of fields, `NF`, is greater than zero and if the line does not start with `//`, then we count it.  At the end, the sum is printed.

If you want to allow for any number of whitespace characters before the `//` on a line (and skip those lines):

```
awk 'NF > 0 && !/^[[:space:]]*\/\// { c++ } END { print c }'
```